# LessCss - Pass parameters of "method" on without redundancy

Tags: css, web, less

Is there a way to avoid the redundancy here:

```
.bg-gradient-glossy(
                @from:top, 

                @from-color-0:rgba(255,255,255,.4),
                @from-percent-0:0%,

                @to-color-0:rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
                @to-percent-0:50%,

                @from-color-1:rgba(255,255,255,0),
                @from-percent-1:50%,

                @to-color-1:rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
                @to-percent-1:100%
        ) {
                .XY.bg-gradient(
                        @from:@from,
                        @from-color-0:@from-color-0,
                        @to-color-0:@to-color-0,
                        @from-color-1:@from-color-1,
                        @to-color-1:@to-color-1,
                        @from-percent-0:@from-percent-0,
                        @to-percent-0:@to-percent-0,
                        @from-percent-1:@from-percent-1,
                        @to-percent-1:@to-percent-1
                );
        }
```

As you can see, I basically just need to pass them on. Is there a **less.apply(this, arguments)** like functionality or a reference to all of the parameters to be passed on?

Comment: Why not directly call the inner mixin instead of using a wrapper?

Comment: Because of the defaults. Any of those values can be overriden.